# windbg scripting finding if a unique_ptr<object> is empty and strings match

Tags: windbg

I have a dump. I am trying to look for objects in memory which contain a specific string.
The `ClassA->name` should be equal to `(18750736-6e77-48a7-9dca-8fdf041e05d2:132257155499245423)` and `ClassA->classC` object should not be `empty` and `ClassA->name` == `ClassA->classC->name2` for a valid `ClassA` object.

```
ClassA
{
   // at offset 0x30
   wstring name; // looking for ClassC objects which have name == (18750736-6e77-48a7-9dca-8fdf041e05d2:132257155499245423)

   unique_ptr<ClassC> classC; // at offset 0xa8
};


ClassC
{
   wstring name2; // name2 == name in a valid object.
};
```

What is the best way to achieve this ?

I wrote following script where i am able to get all the location in memory which has specific string.

I have got offset of the `classC` field. How can i check if the value is `empty` or not and `classC->name2` == `classA->name` ?

I find writing js script is hard as i don't know of how to `interactively` debug the issues in script. Is there any other better way to write windbg scripts ?

```
function log(a1,a2) 
{ 
    host.diagnostics.debugLog(a1 +"    " +a2 + "\n"); 
}

function exec (cmdstr)
{
    return host.namespace.Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand(cmdstr);    
}

function runCommandGetAddresses3()
{
    var temp = exec("s -[w]u 0 L?ffffffff`ffffffff \"(18750736-6e77-48a7-9dca-8fdf041e05d2:132257155499245423)\"").Take(2);
    var addresses = [];

    for ( line of temp ) 
    {
        try
        {
            var token = line.split(" ");
            var addressOfClassAName = token[0];
            var t = exec("dx -r1 ((MyDll!std::unique_ptr<ClassC,std::default_delete<ClassC>>*) (0x" + addressOfClassAName + " - 0x30 + 0xa8))");
            addresses.push(t);
            // how to find if `t` is `empty` or has `value` ?
        }
        catch(ex)
        {
            log(ex, "exception");
        }
    }

    return addresses;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to understand the logic in your script
1)You Search for a Wide String and Take  its Address
and then you start manipulating that address directly ??

**i presume** you know std::wstring is a structure
**I also presume** you know that
the search result you have above is std::wstring.c_str()'s address

**I also presume your understanding of Short String Optimization** in std::wstring

std::wstring will and can embed a short string within itself
or provide a pointer to the string

so **I presume again that you understand** that this address does not have relation with the class A

this address you get by searching the address space will either be within std::wstring

(can not be the case as your string is too long for sso to be invoked)

or a pointer to some arbitrary memory that was allocated by the std::wstring in its
constructor  (probably in Heap Some where)

subtracting 0x30 and adding 0xa8 etc to this address will all result in garbage

you appear to be casting this garbage  address as a pointer to Class C

please correct or edit your post to clarify your intent

i made a quick hack to represent your class A and display it in windbg take a look

```
0:000> dx Debugger.Utility.Control.ExecuteCommand("s -[w]u 1f0000 l?(285000-1f0000) this").Take(2)

    [0x0]            : 002eb048  0074 0068 0069 0073 0020 0069 0073 0020  t.h.i.s. .i.s. .

0:000> ?? (foo._Mypair._Myval2->Aname._Mypair._Myval2._Bx._Ptr)
wchar_t * 0x002eb048
 "this is Aname's name ANAME"

0:000> dx foo
foo                 : unique_ptr {...} [Type: std::unique_ptr<A,std::default_delete<A> >]
    [<Raw View>]     [Type: std::unique_ptr<A,std::default_delete<A> >]
    [ptr]            : 0x2eaf80 [Type: A *]
    [deleter]        : default_delete [Type: std::_Compressed_pair<std::default_delete<A>,A *,1>]
    [+0x000] bf               : "1337" [Type: char [48]]
    [+0x030] Aname            : "this is Aname's name ANAME" [Type: std::basic_string<wchar_t,std::char_traits<wchar_t>,std::allocator<wchar_t> >]
    [+0x048] cf               : ".???" [Type: char [96]]
    [+0x0a8] AnotherClass     : empty [Type: std::unique_ptr<C,std::default_delete<C> >]
```

the Address of foo is 0x18f9d0 you get 0x2eb048 for the wstring search

```
0:000> dx &foo
&foo                 : 0x18f9d0 : unique_ptr {...} [Type: std::unique_ptr<A,std::default_delete<A> > *]
```

the address of std::wstring is in HEAP while std::unique_ptr foo is in stack

std::wstring

```
0:000> !address 0x002eb048

Usage:                  Heap
Base Address:           002e0000
End Address:            002f0000
Region Size:            00010000 (  64.000 kB)
State:                  00001000          MEM_COMMIT
Protect:                00000004          PAGE_READWRITE
Type:                   00020000          MEM_PRIVATE
Allocation Base:        002e0000
Allocation Protect:     00000004          PAGE_READWRITE
More info:              heap owning the address: !heap 0x2e0000
More info:              heap segment
More info:              heap entry containing the address: !heap -x 0x2eb048

0:000> !heap -x 0x002eb048
SEGMENT HEAP ERROR: failed to initialize the extention
Entry     User      Heap      Segment       Size  PrevSize  Unused    Flags
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
002eb040  002eb048  002e0000  002e0000        58        c8        18  busy extra fill
```

std::unique_ptr

```
0:000> !address 0x18f9d0

Usage:                  Stack
Base Address:           0018d000
End Address:            00190000
Region Size:            00003000 (  12.000 kB)
State:                  00001000          MEM_COMMIT
Protect:                00000004          PAGE_READWRITE
Type:                   00020000          MEM_PRIVATE
Allocation Base:        00090000
Allocation Protect:     00000004          PAGE_READWRITE
More info:              ~0k

0:000> ~0k
 # ChildEBP RetAddr  
00 0018f9e0 00216f4c smartptr!main+0x198 smartptr.cpp @ 26 
01 (Inline) -------- smartptr!invoke_main+0x1c 
02 0018fa28 762ced6c smartptr!__scrt_common_main_seh+0xfa 
03 0018fa34 779b37eb kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk+0xe
04 0018fa74 779b37be ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart+0x70
05 0018fa8c 00000000 ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart+0x1b
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out these descrepencies..
My main question was about how to do conditional logic in windbg script ? Can you please answer that ?
See this line in script
`// how to find if t is empty or has value ?`